# Json insertion into scylla table

Tags: scylla

I am trying to insert json data into my scylla table but it is vomiting an error the commnd given is

```
Insert into students json '{"lastname" :"Roy", "firstname" :"Kumar", "id" :2} `;
```

And the error is

> Syntax exception : line 1:33 missing ' (' at' '

Any one please help me in this issue how to resolve?

Comment: FYI, Scylla 2.3 was officially released last week and includes support for JSON inserts. Read about it here: https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/json/

Answer (score 6):

INSERT JSON support is only available in Scylla 2.3. You can test a preview release [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/scylladb/scylla/tags/).

Answer (score 1):

Scylla 2.3 was officially released last week and includes support for JSON inserts. Read more about it [here](https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/json/).